# Convert date to string in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, date, criteria, sql-like

Is it possible to perform a request that checks the string representation of a Date instance. For example

```
Restrictions.like("dateField", "%12%")
```

to retrieve dates that either have String 12 in day or 12 in month or 12 in year where "dateField" is an instance of java.util.Date
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and here's what I did:

First, I created my own Criterion implementation:

```
public class DateLikeExpression implements Criterion {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String propertyName;
private String value;

public DateLikeExpression(String propertyName, String value) {
    this.propertyName = propertyName;
    this.value = value;
}

public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
    String[] columns = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, propertyName);
    if (columns.length != 1) {
        throw new HibernateException("Like may only be used with single-column properties");
    }
    return "to_char(" + columns[0] + ", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') like ?";
}

public TypedValue[] getTypedValues(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
    return new TypedValue[] { new TypedValue(new org.hibernate.type.StringType(),
            MatchMode.START.toMatchString(value.toLowerCase()), EntityMode.POJO) };
}

}
```

Then, I just use it when I put the Criteria together:

```
criteria.add(new DateLikeExpression("dateColumnName", "26/11%"));
```

And that's about it. Note that this implementation **is** locale-dependent (pt_BR in this case) and works for postgresql, which has the to_char function. You might have to tweak it a little bit to work with your database engine.

Comment: PS: This is sql-injection-safe, unlike the other answer below.

Comment: This is not working for me. What is it that I might be missing?

Comment: @MitalPritmani which database are you using? Which locale? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL. Locale - IST. I'm not getting any error but it's not working.I saw in sql by `showsql=true`,this criteria is not in the query at all while other criterias are there!! I've written exactly this class and used it as you have suggested. I've same requirement - converting date to string so can match some numbers.

Comment: @MitalPritmani it's hard to help you out without looking at your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I had done a silly mistake, was calling some other method. This works. Thanks. :) Depending on the requirement, now I'm using sqlRestriction directly as this class also does same. Somehow I feel both these solutions restrict it to some specific database so if database changes, code for this may also change.

Comment: @MitalPritmani the class doesn't use sqlRestriction. With sqlRestriction you have to be careful about SQL Injection. The solution I presented takes care of that. And about being database specific, I hear your point. But again, how often does your database engine change?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("month(dateField) = 12");
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("right(year(dateField),2) = 12");
```

The part within the [sqlRestriction](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29) depends on which database you are using.

Comment: If you're searching for an user-provided value, you'll lose the hibernate safeguards against sql injection. You need to be pretty careful about how to deal with the input. And odds are the average programmer won't cover all the basis. You can use the cast function in prepared HQL queries to convert your date into a string (if the db supports that) and you should be safe from sql injection.