# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%0%] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am building a **like** predicate using hibernate to match a string against date.
So for e.g. if my date is 09/08/2016 and if user enters 09, then this value should be matched.

I tried the following:

```
criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.toString(root.get("dateField")),
                        '%'+ value.toLowerCase() + '%');
```

`dateField` in my java class is `java.util.date` and in my db it is timestamp.

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%0%] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765559/convert-date-to-string-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL, it worked !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The date must be sent in ISO format

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Example to code JAVA:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
sdf.format(atStartOfDay(DATE_DAY));
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Only (1) Hardcoding `Z` as a literal is wrong. It’s a UTC offset. (2) Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.